# Provide API for a Django project as a different docker service

Tags: django, docker, django-rest-framework

I recently started to work on a friend's project in Django and we want to provide a REST API so other projects can consume our data. I'm starting to learn  django-rest-framework (and django-rest-swagger for documentation). Is it possible to create the API as a separate service? this way we dockerize it and serve the api in one container, and keep the application on its original container preventing that if many requests  to the API were made, it will not interfere on the application (by bringing it down for example). If it is not possible what is the best way for implement the API on the project?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible. [See here](https://medium.com/backticks-tildes/how-to-dockerize-a-django-application-a42df0cb0a99). Structurally, you will probably want to write the project by keeping all presentation-related apps separate from the API-related apps.

Comment: Thanks for the response! If i put the presentation-related apps in a separated container from the API-related apps, Would I still have to do the presentation-related request the data via API? or can I have a more direct way to get the data? If my API server get down by to many requests, will my application (the presentation- apps)  also get down? or i can still request the data locally and only the external services will be affected?